# Gerrit authentication and user as per Company ID

Tags: git, authentication, gerrit

I am fairly new to Gerrit! I want to begin its evaluation but stuck at Register/Log-In. It requires Open-Id but my company email doesn't support Open-ID.
If I implement Gerrit in my Cmpny then I have to give their Sign-In Id as company ID only.

How can I do it? i.e Use the company's email id to register/login to gerrit or can I use the Linux Server User-Accounts on which Gerrit is running to login.

Any help on Authentication in Gerrit or how it happens around the world would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are different authentication methods [available](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11/config-gerrit.html#auth) in Gerrit, including LDAP and HTTP auth through the reverse proxy in front of Gerrit (with Apache HTTPd's external auth, you can authenticate using a custom executable).